# Fire events from ServiceHost interface

Tags: c#, wcf, events

I'm followed this example to create a WCF interface between two C# projects:

https://dopeydev.com/wcf-interprocess-communication/

as you can see in the "TestService.cs" code, there is an implementation of this function:

```
public void SendMessage(string message)
{
    MessageBox.Show(message);
}
```

which actually shows the received message on the server. I know the name is quite confusing, but it's the same name the client would use.

My goal is to change this function in order to fire an event to be consumed in another class.

This is what I tried to do:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class IServer : Interfaces.IService
{
    public void Connect()
    {
        Callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<Interfaces.ICallbackService>();
    }

    public static Interfaces.ICallbackService Callback { get; set; }

    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        MessageReceivedEventArgs args = new MessageReceivedEventArgs();
        args.json = message;
        OnMessageReceived(this, args);
    }

    public event EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs> MessageReceived;
    protected virtual void OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageReceived?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}

public class MessageReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string json;
}
```

then in my other class:

```
class Comm 
{
    IServer m_server = new IServer();

    public Engine()
    {
        var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(IServer), new Uri("net.pipe://localhost"));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "ipc");
        host.Open();

        m_server.MessageReceived += Server_MessageReceived;
    }

    private void Server_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // this event handler is never executed!
    }
}
```

As far as I understand, the problem is I create a new instance of the `IServer` class with the event handler added, but the `ServiceHost` which actually uses the `IServer` code is another instance.

Am I wrong?
I need to retrieve the instance used by `ServiceHost` to get the event working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ServiceHost` has [an overload where you can provide your own instance for the service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585487(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var host = new ServiceHost(m_server, new Uri("net.pipe://localhost"));
```

Also, you should bind the event **before** starting the service, otherwise you could miss requests:

```
m_server.MessageReceived += Server_MessageReceived;
host.Open();
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. For others who will have the same problem I add I had to change this line in Server code: `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]`